# Цикл по перечислению

Tags: c#

Что нужно добавить в код, чтобы он заработал?

```
public enum Season
{
    Winter,
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autumn
}

foreach (Season s in ...)
{
    // Обработать s
}
```

Наверняка ведь C# это как-то позволяет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (Season s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Season)))
{}
```

Имеется ввиду System.Enum. [См.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc138362(v=vs.90).aspx)